# c# System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType.Cert is this DER?

Tags: c#, x509certificate

How can I be sure that my exported certificate file is **DER** encoded? 
Is there a way to check the file?

I can export a certificate loaded into memory to a file

```
string strFilename = _rksvpath + cert.GetSerialNumberString() + ".cer";
byte[] bytesCertExport = cert.Export(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType.Cert);
File.WriteAllBytes(strFilename, bytesCertExport);
```

and the file is OK, which I can prove with certutil

```
C:\>certutil -dump C:\temp\0104A73D4557FCE026120AC356.cer
X.509-Zertifikat:
Version: 3
Seriennummer: 0104a73d4557fce026120ac356
Signaturalgorithmus:
Algorithmus Objekt-ID: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 sha256RSA
Algorithmusparameter: 05 00
...
```

However, I can not find any information about the encoding in the output of certutil, or in the windows certificate-viewer (opened with below command)

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" cryptext.dll,CryptExtOpenCER C:\temp\0104A73D4557FCE026120AC356.cer
```

Answer (score 0):

X.509 certificates are always encoded by using Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER).

The only difference is how DER value is stored in the file, either an exact binary copy or when binary data is encoded by using Base64. Standard tools do not tell what file format is used (binary, or Base64). You can read the first byte of the file. If it is ASCII 48, then the file is exact binary copy of the certificate, otherwise, binary copy is base64-encoded with or without PEM header/footer.